# How to split unique values of list generated from str.findall into separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on the Kaggle Titanic dataset and there's a Cabin column (see below) with multiple rooms. I generated 'Deck' using `# train_df['Deck']= train_df['Cabin'].str.findall('[A-Z]')` and want to obtain 'Deck 1' and 'Deck 2'. How do I generate the columns 'Deck 1' and 'Deck 2'?

| Cabin | Deck | Deck 1 | Deck 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C16 C18 | C | C |  |
| C1 | [C] | C |  |
| E1 F2 | [E,F] | E | F |

Comment: `df['Deck'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',', expand = True)`